# Is the combination of `<$>`/`<*>`/`join` equivalent to `>>=`?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

As of my understanding both monadic operations should be equally expressive:

```
(^2) >>= (\x -> if x == 4 then \_ -> [] else (+1) >>= (\y -> negate >>= (\z env -> [x, y, z, env]))) $ 2
--                             ^^    

join (((\x -> if x == 4 then \_ _ _ -> [] else \y z env -> [x, y, env, z]) <$> (^2)) <*> (+1)) <*> (negate) $ 2
--                           ^^^^^^
```

(please feel free to indent the code above, since I don't know how to do it without breaking the syntax)

Both computations yield the same result `[]`, however, they differ in that only the latter short circuits whereas the former has to go through the entire structure. This isn't a problem as long as the effect can be ignored and is thus kind of idempotent, which certainly doesn't hold for every possible instance.

I am probably using `join` incorrectly, but I cannot see how to obtain short circuiting with the applicaitve computation. It seems as if short circuit semantics arises from the nested structure of monadic computations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by short-circuiting. Remember that Haskell has non-strict semantics, so from a certain perspective pretty much anything short-circuits until it can't anymore. Aside from that, it's an established mathematical fact that, once you have `fmap` (equivalently, `<$>`), you can define `join` and `>>=` in terms of one another and get exactly equivalent behavior. If you find a monad where this rule breaks down, you've found an invalid monad, and you should consider reporting a bug to the author of that library.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo If you use `join` as the outermost operation of an otherwise applicative computation you defer the merging of two contexts until the end of the computation and hence cannot determine the next effect by a previous value. This only works if you replace each occurence of `>>=` with `fmap` followed by `join`,

Answer (score 6):

It's always the case that

```
join m = m >>= id
m >>= f = join (f <$> m)
```

You can use these laws to convert between `join` and `>>=`.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: By replacing `>>=` with `join (f <$> m)` we can maintain the same nested structure.